# Problem regarding differentiating under the integral

Tags: integration

A problem I'm working on requires me to differentiate $\int_0^t \!f(x+a(y-t),y) dy$ with respect to $t$. I understand that the formula to use is

$\frac{d}{dx}\ (\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \!f(x,t) dt) = f(x,b(x))b'(x) - f(x,a(x))a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \!f_x(x,t) dt$

But I don't know how to apply this formula to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dt} \int^t_0 f(x+a(y-t),y )dy = f(x,t)\cdot 1 + \int^t_0\frac{\partial}{\partial e_1} f(x+a(y-t),y )dy\cdot (-a)$$
The first term on the rhs is just the integrand evaluated at $y=t$. The term with $t$ in the first argument thus vanishes ($t-t=0$). The derivative of $b(t)=t$ is $=1$.

There is no term resulting from the lower integral bound, since it is constant. I used the notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial e_1}$ to indicate partial derivative wrt to the first argument, since $x,y$ are in use already. $-a$ is just the derivative of the first argument wrt $t$, the second argument of the integrand does not depend on $t$ so it produces no term.

(note: I read $a(y-t)$ as a constant $a$ times $y-t$. If $a$ is a function, then the factor $-a$ has to be replaced by $-a^\prime(y-t)$ and needs to remain under the integral).